# Unremovable top space when using Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In this [sample page](http://carlhuang.com/sample.html), I cannot find a way to eliminate the space on left column and the top of the browser window. I have tried setting all top paddings and margins to 0 either manually or using the `.mt-0` and `.pt-0` class, but so far to no avail.

[image]

I thought the code was relatively straightforward (shown below), and would appreciate if someone can point out where the issue is.

```
<body>　
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 bg-light">
                left column
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                right column
            </div> <!-- End right column -->
        </div>  <!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why but it appears if you retype your `<body>` tag it seems to work fine. Maybe the characters are not being recognized?

Comment: Thanks. I reviewed my code after reading your suggestion and found a trailing space right after the `<body>` tag. Retyping `<body>` or removing the space character can both successfully resolve this issue.